# Password Recovery Software Not Working Properly

Tags: batch-file, password-recovery

I am using the password recovery software called WebBrowserPassView (found on this website http://nirsoft.net/). The software works fine, but I want a batch file to automate the process of saving the passwords onto my computer.

This is what is in the batch file

```
start WebBrowserPassView.exe /shtml log.txt
```

But when I run it, it only opens the password recovery software, it does not create a text file at all.
I also tried

```
start WebBrowserPassView.exe /shtml "log.txt"
```

But that doesn't work either.
What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

On their website they give the command "/shtml " and it has this description "Save the passwords list into HTML file (Horizontal).". I am not sure how to implement this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the site itself, you should simply do the following...

```
WebBrowserPassView.exe /shtml <Filename>
```

So, I guess just enter a valid .html file name. E.g.

```
WebBrowserPassView.exe /shtml output.html
```

Or use /stext to export to a text file...

```
WebBrowserPassView.exe /stext output.txt
```

Or CSV...

```
WebBrowserPassView.exe /scomma output.csv
```

It should output the resultant file in the same directory that you run it. If not, try putting a full path in there instead of just the filename. If it doesn't work with that, then it's a problem with their application and you'll need to contact their support people.

http://nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_password.html

Comment: I tried this but it just opened the program and made an empty text file. The site I got this from has a list of batch commands that work with the software, but I'm not sure how to implement them...

Comment: Can you copy the commands that they suggest in your question? I'm not going to an external URL to check. Sorry.

Comment: Okay, I added the info. It is just a command that they list, I'm just not sure if I am coding it the right way.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if i recall, this should work;

```
start "" "WebBrowserPassView.exe" /stext "passOutput"
:: Then rename it to your desired [.log]
ren "passOutput.txt" "passOutput.log"
```

As the parameters don't allow for alternate extensions, and sometimes ignore parameters completely.